# How to make .unclick = unbind('click' in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a shortcut notation for unbind('click'. I want .unclick to be unbind('click'.

Comment: Spend more than 5 seconds on phrasing your question and it might actually resemble a question :)

Comment: what? do you want to unbind a click event?

Comment: @TStamper - I think he wants to unbind an unclick uneventhandler. Isn't it obvious?

Comment: @Karim79- not to me, if it was obvious, I would have edited the question to be more clear

Comment: Hey may want to extend the jquery object to allow something like "$obj.unclick(handler)" to remove that handler from the onclick event of the underlying DOM objects.

Comment: @TStamper - I was only making a joke. It's highly unobvious :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
$.fn['unclick'] = function(){
   return this.unbind('click');
};
```

Now the following two lines are equivalent:

```
$(...).unbind('click');
$(...).unclick();
```

---

For all events (list of events copied from the [jQuery source](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js)):

```
var events = ('blur,focus,load,resize,scroll,unload,click,dblclick,' +
              'mousedown,mouseup,mousemove,mouseover,mouseout,mouseenter,' +
              'mouseleave,change,select,submit,keydown,keypress,keyup,error'
             ).split(',');

jQuery.each(events, function(i, name){
    jQuery.fn['un' + name] = function(){
        return this.unbind(name);
    };
});
```

Comment: +1 That looks pretty good, but think you meant unclick as opposed to unlick :)

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling extend...?

Comment: @Josh: to be honest I'm not aware of the difference between calling extend and what I'm doing (I'm a javascript novice). I would like to point of that the jQuery source employs both techniques. Can you explain the benefits of calling extend?

Comment: @Stephan202: Extend is the way jQuery wants it. Theoretically it's the same, but depending on the implementation of jQuery it could also differ. (What happens if there is already a unlink function etc.?)

Comment: There's no difference. Using jQuery.extend() is only useful for adding multiple plugins.

Answer (score 3):

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
      unclick: function() {
        return this.unbind('click');
      }
});
```

Comment: Nope, no benefit in using extend()... Just more characters.